# Call a Python function that expects keyboard input with data from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using a C/C++ analogy, I want to pipe the contents of a file to stdin.

I have a Python function that prompts users for student name and grade and creates a list of lists. Instead of typing a 100 names and grades, I want to put the names and grades in a text file and provide that as input to this function.  How do I do this? Code fragment below:

```
def enter_grades(num_students):
    class_grades = []
    for i in range(num_students):
       class_grades.append([input(), float(input())])
    print( class_grades)
    return class_grades
```

There is a file "grades.txt" with student names and grades.  Want to provide its contents as input to enter_grades().

Comment: I want to use the file to test the function with a lot of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are finding the python version of `freopen()`.

You can set the `sys.stdin` to a file object simply do the following:

```
import sys

sys.stdin = open("/path/to/file.txt", "r")
text = input()
print(text)
```

The `input()` function will now read data from file instead of user input.

**More Usage**

Similarly, if you want to redirect the standard output or standard error to a file, just set the corresponding variables in `sys`:

```
sys.stdout = open("stdout.txt", "w")
sys.stderr = open("stderr.txt", "w")
```